# Update the select box after adding a new entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, drop-down-menu

I have two jsp pages add.jsp and view.jsp. There is a dropdown list with all userids on view page which will be automatically fetched from database when the page loads (I'm using document.ready event to retrieve the values).

When i add a new user on add.jsp page and click submit, it will redirect to view.jsp page with a success message. However, the dropdown will not show the new userid added. I have to close and re-run the project so that it appears next time.

How to append the select box with newly added user ?

```
    view.jsp

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('MyController', function(response){
        var $select = $(#myselect);
        $.each(response,function(key,value){
            $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);
        });
    });
});
</script>
..
..
..
<body><form>
<select id=myselect></select>
</form>
</body></html>

Mycontroller.java

doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
//construct json object
//write to response

}

doPost (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
//adduser to DB
//return userId generated
/*send the generated id to view.jsp page*/

RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("view.jsp");
req.setattribute("generatedId",id);
rd.forward(req,res);
}


The generated Id is sent to view.jsp page. I want to append this new id to the select box in view page along with the existing id's
(which were already loaded using javascript).
```

Comment: will you enter userid in any textbox are it is autogenerated in database..?

Comment: @Venkata Krishna Reddy Autogenerated in database

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fetching the vales from database on page load your dropdown will not be getupdated untill page reloads.. if want to update with out refresh what you need to do is capture userid from textbox on submit click you need to append for drop down of if userid generated by database return updated data from your controller on sucess of ajax bind it to dropdown

```
var newOption = $('<option value="'+yournewvalue+'">'+yournewvalue+'</option>');
 $('#yourdropdownid').append(newOption);
```

Comment: I am returning the updated data from controller on success. However i'm forwarding the data to a new page different from where the event originated. i.e submit button on add page and the dropdown on view page. How to bind to dropdown. i already have a document ready function associated with this dropdown

Comment: It works as expected now ,though I have not changed anything. Thanks